# JavaScript Prompt() is showing up twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the JavasScript prompt to take input from the user to take feedback before submitting the form. Everything is working well but one issue I am facing is javascript Prompt() show up twice in on click. I don't know why?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#refuse_request").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    promptfunction();
  });
});

function promptfunction() {
  var comment = prompt("Add your comment", 'Comment Here');
  console.log(comment)
  if (comment == "") {
    document.getElementById("comment_refuse").value = 'No comment is given by user';
    console.log(document.getElementById("comment_refuse").value)
    //$('#refuse_form').submit();
  } else if (comment != null && comment != "") {
    document.getElementById("comment_refuse").value = comment;
    console.log(document.getElementById("comment_refuse").value)
    //$('#refuse_form').submit();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" id="refuse_form">
  <input type="text" name="req_to" hidden>
  <input type="text" name="req_of" hidden>
  <input type="text" name="ans" value="Refuse" hidden>
  <input type="text" name="comment_of" id="comment_refuse" value="" hidden>
  <button type="submit" id="refuse_request" style="color:red;" class="btn">click</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you also share the HTML for above code?

Comment: Please reformat your source code, it isn't very readable, at the end of your console.log(comment) add a ';' and put the if on a new line.  Also, never assume a function return will always be successful, your call to getElementById() then references value without checking the return which could be "undefined".  Asssign it once to a temporary variable:  var refuse = document.getElementById("comment_refuse");  check that refuse is not undefined then use it instead of the multiple calls you have now.

Comment: FYI: ‘prompt()’ is a method of the ‘window’ object. It’s not part of the JavaScript/ECMAScript language.

Comment: May be can try move the <button> out from the <form>?

Comment: no its also not working

Comment: Because you have this in the function `$('#refuse_form').submit()`

Comment: why would you want the function to fire on click of the entire form? `$("#refuse_request").click()` ... shouldn't be only upon submit `.submit()`... if you use `click` no matter where you click inside that form, it will always fire... or at least, you should have on the button click and not the whole form...

Comment: yes I had tried the button click too it's still not working for my case.

Comment: @balexandre `#refuse_request` *is* the submit button, not the entire form. `<button type="submit" id="refuse_request"` `<form method="POST" id="refuse_form">`

Comment: **EDIT** I've updated your code to be a snippet.  As you can see, there's nothing wrong with the code and the "prompt" only runs once *(I did disable `.submit()` for use in the snippet)*.  Please update the snippet to provide a [mcve] that *demonstrates* the issue.

Comment: It is working fine. I just copy and paste this code in an HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

You code are a really big mess, try put a semicolon (;) to close the console statement before the "if", so here the "bug" doesn't happen, if the problem persist, put your code in a snippet so will be more easy to help you,  and is a good idea set the message of the prompt into a variable like this

```
<script>
  function promptfunction() {
    var msg = "In order to improve our match requests, \n please explain us why...";
    var comment = prompt(msg);
    console.log(comment);
    if (comment == "") {
      document.getElementById("comment_refuse").value ="No comment is given by user";
      console.log(document.getElementById("comment_refuse").value);
      $("#refuse_form").submit();
    } else if (comment != null && comment != "") {
      document.getElementById("comment_refuse").value = comment;
      console.log(document.getElementById("comment_refuse").value);
      $("#refuse_form").submit();
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: These are minor layout changes/advise, there are no functional changes here and they don't *answer* the problem.  Making these changes will not fix OPs problem.

Comment: I just put here for the code example, because his code was a mess, and it seems work without the "problem" mentioned, but I clearly understand your point so I'm wait for his feedback to properly help him

Comment: thanks for your help but this also don't solve the issue. I am working on a Django framework and its backend is in python. I know for sure that backend is not an issue for this case. my code is the same as its above for this module. if you want the complete HTML as JS file please let me know I'll share it with you.